# In bakeries, what are the factors that make breads become hard?

Tags: baking, bread, reheating

If breads are reheated in a bakery, will this cause the bread to become hard?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'hard'? Are you talking about the interior structure? The crust?

Comment: @mrwienerdog I would assume that the OP means the crust